# XAML user control / window sizing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created a basic framework that lets me display views within a modal dialog. The "container" window looks something like this (just the XAML pertinent to my problem):-

```
<Window SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        ResizeMode="{Binding DialogResizeMode}">        
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <!-- This is where the buttons are rendered -->
        </Border>

        <ContentControl />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Views (UserControls) are placed in the `ContentControl`, with a typical view looking something like this:-

```
<UserControl ..the usual stuff..
             Width="500"
             Height="400">
   <!-- etc. -->
</UserControl>
```

By setting the width and height, it means the view can effectively control the dimensions of the modal dialog (due to the container window's `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` setting).

The problem is, I now need to make the dialog resizable in some scenarios. If I set the parent Window's `ResizeMode` to `CanResize`, the user control remains at its fixed size in the centre of the dialog as the window is resized.

I suspect I'll need to use a different approach to setting the initial window size, such as providing the width and height for the window to bind to (unless I'm missing a simple solution). Any suggestions?

**Edit**

I've found a solution by removing the `SizeToContent` option from the parent window, and removing the Width & Height from the user control XAMl. I now set the window size from the user control's Loaded event:-

```
var window = Window.GetWindow(this);
window.Width = 500;
window.Height = 400;
```

It feels a bit hacky though - it would be nice if this could be accomplished using a XAML-only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is preventing you from binding to your `ResizeMode` property, and using `Style` triggers to set the properties? Something along the lines of,

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
       <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ResizeMode, RelatveSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="NoResize">
                     <Setter Property="Width" Value="500"></Setter>
                     <Setter Property="Height" Value="400"></Setter>
               </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I want the user control (view) to set the window's dimensions, not the other way round. The window is a container that I use to display views as modal dialogs, and as explained above I would set the view's width & height and the window would size to fit the content. I now have a requirement to show a resizable dialog, but this trick doesn't work when the parent window's ResizeMode=CanResize - the window does initially appear at the correct size, but as you drag it larger the UC stays in the centre of the window at its "fixed" dimensions.

Comment: In the above style, if you add another trigger for `CanResize` and set horizontal and vertical alignment to `Stretch`, with `MinHeight` and `MinWidth` instead of `Height` and `Width`, what happens?